# Setcounter but for itemize

Tags: itemize, setcounter

I want to have an itemize environment where for each item the label of the equations change. For example, in the first item I want to have all equations labeled $(1.x)$, and so on, where $x$ resets in each new item. Is there a way to do with this some form of counter? I have done it for sections before, but can find no literature on doing something similar for itemize.

When I naively just use \setcounter{section}{item number} i get the correct label for the first entry, but $x$ never resets.

Edit:

I'm essentially solving problem sets, and the type face of itemize is preferable for me. Essentially I write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{Problem 1:}] Insert problem statement

Insert solution 1

\item[\textbf{Problem 2:}] Insert problem statement

Insert solution 2

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the equations I write in each problem section to be numbered differently so I my equations don't stack up and they are easy to reference.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, what you are asking for. Can you please show an example (e.g. with manual `\item[…]` arguments). I also do not understand, why you want to use `itemize` instead of `enumerate`. Numbered lists are usually `enumerate` or derived environments.

Comment: I wish to use itemize because it allows me to \item[Problem 1], and I can make parts A through Z of some problem just new items. It's just how I've formatted my homework in the past.

Comment: If you add a bit more of the explanation of what you're doing to the question we can re-open the question.

Comment: (It would have been nicer if your example had included the equations that you're trying to number.)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for an enumerated list (not a itemized list) in which equations within an item will be numbered relative to that item.  If that's correct, the following might be what you have in mind.

If you really want an itemize list but with the equations the same way, you can change the `label` code to be `label=\textbullet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlist{eqlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist*[eqlist]{leftmargin=*,label=\bfseries Example \arabic*,ref=\arabic*}
\counterwithin{equation}{eqlisti}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqlist}
\item
\begin{equation}
f = ma
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x
\end{equation}
\item
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}
\end{eqlist}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you want to use the actual `itemize` environment to do this, as you suggest in your comment, you could create a counter to build the equation numbers off of. Here I've created a `\probitem` command to introduce the problem number (since I assume these will not necessarily be in order).  This seems more in line with what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{myitemcounter}
\counterwithin{equation}{myitemcounter}
\NewDocumentCommand{\probitem}{m}{\setcounter{myitemcounter}{#1-1}\item[Problem #1]}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[before=\setcounter{myitemcounter}{0}\pretocmd{\item}{\stepcounter{myitemcounter}}{}{},wide,font=\bfseries]
\probitem{1}
\begin{equation}
f = ma
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x
\end{equation}
\probitem{3}
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of second example]

Comment: Why can't I use the itemize environment?

Comment: Well the itemize doesn't have a counter that you can build the equation numbers off of; you could add a counter inside the itemize itself just for the equation numbering if you really wanted to, but I don't really see the purpose behind it.

Comment: @Chris Now that you've explained a bit more what you're doing, I've added a way to do that, which I think now does what you want.

Comment: This only works if all equations are included in problems, right? I guess it sounds like that might work in this case, though, so maybe not a problem.

Comment: @cfr what do you mean?

Comment: @Chris If you have equations outside of the itemize environments their numbers won’t make much sense since the equation counter depends on the itemize counter.